# How to separate scss function returned values

Tags: css, function, sass, compass-sass, scss-mixins

I have two SCSS maps call `$my-map-1` and `$my-map-2`. Each map has the keys with their hex value. I wrote a function to return the key and the hex values (`$key`, `$value`) of each map separately.

After that, I wrote a `@if` condition with my function to check the map. I pass my map name to the function. If map there, check is the `$key` equal to the given name. If that true, pass the `$valu` of that `$key` to my color mixin. This is my code.

```
$my-map-1: (
        map-1-color-1: #506c89,
        map-1-color-2: #737373,
        map-1-color-3: #2a3949,
        map-1-color-4: #182028,
);

$my-map-2: (
        map-2-color-1: #fff,
        map-2-color-2: #000,
        map-2-color-3: #ddd,
        map-2-color-4: #ccc,
);

//the function to read te map and return the key and the value.
@function color-map($color-map) {
  @each $key, $value in $color-map {    
    @return ($key, $value);
  }
}

//mixin
@mixin color-mix($color){
  color: $color;
}

//css classes from here
@if color-map($my-map-1) {
  if($key == map-1-color-1) {
    .my-class{
      @include color-mix($color:$value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want a mixin to check, passing as argument a map, if in that map there is a key calls `map-1-color-1`. If there is you want create a class `.my-class` with as `color` the hexadecimal of `map-1-color-1`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. That is what I need. 

I wrote it use an `@each` condition like this.

`@each $key , $value in $my-map-1{
  @if ($key == map-1-color-1){
    .my-class{
      @include color-mix($color:$value);
    }
  }
}`

But I need to do it using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map-get` method, it is very useful: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method

This is an example of mixin. I pass as argument also your key: maybe it is better because you can check also others key names, if you need it:

```
$my-map-1: (
  map-1-color-1: #506c89,
  map-1-color-2: #737373,
  map-1-color-3: #2a3949,
  map-1-color-4: #182028
);

$my-map-2: (
  map-2-color-1: #fff,
  map-2-color-2: #000,
  map-2-color-3: #ddd,
  map-2-color-4: #ccc
);


@mixin color-map($color-map, $key-map) {
  @each $key, $value in $color-map {    
    @if($key == $key-map) {
      .my-class{
        color: map-get($color-map, $key);
      }
    }
  }
}

@include color-map($my-map-1, map-1-color-1);
```

Your output will be:

```
.my-class {
  color: #506c89;
}
```

Comment: Yes! It is working. Thank you very much for your kind support. Hope you will help me next time too. See you again. Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome. It was a pleasure to help you! Have a nice day too. :-)